# How to convert a .dcm file to a pdf file?

Tags: java, dcm4che

To convert a pdf file I used the pdf2dcm.java class. But ,now I need to convert dicom files to pdf in order to read the content of the document. How to do that? Is there any java class able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Dcm4che has what you're looking for. Please have a look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/

Comment: I didn't find the appropriate class.

Answer (score 0):

First you can convert DCM to jpg then JPG to PDF

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class DCM2JPG_Convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       try{
            File src = new File("d:\\CHESTP.dcm");
            File dest = new File("d:\\CHEST_PA12.jpg");           
            Dcm2Jpeg dcm2jpg= new Dcm2Jpeg();           
            dcm2jpg.convert(src, dest);         
            System.out.println("Completed");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject;
import org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam;
import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.util.CloseUtils;

import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;


public class Dcm2Jpeg {

    private static final String USAGE =
        "dcm2jpg [Options] <dcmfile> <jpegfile>\n" +
        "or dcm2jpg [Options] <dcmfile>... <outdir>\n" +
        "or dcm2jpg [Options] <indir>... <outdir>";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = 
        "Convert DICOM image(s) to JPEG(s)\nOptions:";
    private static final String EXAMPLE = null;
    private int frame = 1;
    private float center;
    private float width;
    private String vlutFct;
    private boolean autoWindowing;
    private DicomObject prState;
    private short[] pval2gray;
    private String fileExt = ".jpg";

    private void setFrameNumber(int frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    private void setWindowCenter(float center) {
        this.center = center;        
    }

    private void setWindowWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;       
    }

    public final void setVoiLutFunction(String vlutFct) {
        this.vlutFct = vlutFct;
    }    

    private final void setAutoWindowing(boolean autoWindowing) {
        this.autoWindowing = autoWindowing;
    }

    private final void setPresentationState(DicomObject prState) {
        this.prState = prState;        
    }

    private final void setPValue2Gray(short[] pval2gray) {
        this.pval2gray = pval2gray;
    }

    public final void setFileExt(String fileExt) {
        this.fileExt = fileExt;
    }

    public void convert(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
        ImageReader reader = iter.next();
        DicomImageReadParam param = 
            (DicomImageReadParam) reader.getDefaultReadParam();
        param.setWindowCenter(center);
        param.setWindowWidth(width);
        param.setVoiLutFunction(vlutFct);
        param.setPresentationState(prState);
        param.setPValue2Gray(pval2gray);
        param.setAutoWindowing(autoWindowing);
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(src);
        BufferedImage bi;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            reader.setInput(iis, false);
            bi = reader.read(frame - 1, param);
            if (bi == null) {
                System.out.println("\nError: " + src + " - couldn't read!");
                return;
            }
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
            JPEGImageEncoder enc = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
            enc.encode(bi);
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.safeClose(iis);
            CloseUtils.safeClose(out);
        }
        //System.out.print('.');
    }

    public int mconvert(List<String> args, int optind, File destDir)
            throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = optind, n = args.size() - 1; i < n; ++i) {
            File src = new File(args.get(i));
            count += mconvert(src, new File(destDir, src2dest(src)));
        }
        return count;
    }

    private String src2dest(File src) {
        String srcname = src.getName();
        return src.isFile() ? srcname + this.fileExt : srcname;
    }

    public int mconvert(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        if (!src.exists()) {
            System.err.println("WARNING: No such file or directory: " + src
                    + " - skipped.");                
            return 0;
        }
        if (src.isFile()) {
            try {
                convert(src, dest);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("WARNING: Failed to convert " + src + ":");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.out.print('F');
                return 0;
            }
            System.out.print('.');
            return 1;
        }
        File[] files = src.listFiles();
        if (files.length > 0 && !dest.exists()) {
            dest.mkdirs();
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            count += mconvert(files[i], new File(dest, src2dest(files[i])));
        }
        return count;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CommandLine cl = parse(args);
        Dcm2Jpeg dcm2jpg = new Dcm2Jpeg();
        if (cl.hasOption("f")) {
            dcm2jpg.setFrameNumber(
                    parseInt(cl.getOptionValue("f"),
                            "illegal argument of option -f",
                            1, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("p")) {
            dcm2jpg.setPresentationState(loadDicomObject(
                    new File(cl.getOptionValue("p"))));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("pv2gray")) {
            dcm2jpg.setPValue2Gray(loadPVal2Gray(
                    new File(cl.getOptionValue("pv2gray"))));
        }        
        if (cl.hasOption("c")) {
            dcm2jpg.setWindowCenter(
                    parseFloat(cl.getOptionValue("c"),
                            "illegal argument of option -c"));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("w")) {
            dcm2jpg.setWindowWidth(
                    parseFloat(cl.getOptionValue("w"),
                            "illegal argument of option -w"));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("sigmoid")) {
            dcm2jpg.setVoiLutFunction(DicomImageReadParam.SIGMOID);
        }
        dcm2jpg.setAutoWindowing(!cl.hasOption("noauto"));
        if (cl.hasOption("jpgext")) {
            dcm2jpg.setFileExt(cl.getOptionValue("jpgext"));
        }
        final List<String> argList = cl.getArgList();
        int argc = argList.size();

        File dest = new File(argList.get(argc-1));
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int count = 1;
        if (dest.isDirectory()) {
            count = dcm2jpg.mconvert(argList, 0, dest);
        } else {
            File src = new File(argList.get(0));
            if (argc > 2 || src.isDirectory()) {
                exit("dcm2jpg: when converting several files, "
                        + "last argument must be a directory\n");
            }
            dcm2jpg.convert(src, dest);
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("\nconverted " + count + " files in " + (t2 - t1)
                / 1000f + " s.");
    }

    private static DicomObject loadDicomObject(File file) {
        DicomInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new DicomInputStream(file);
            return in.readDicomObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exit(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.safeClose(in);
        }
}

private static short[] loadPVal2Gray(File file) {
        BufferedReader r = null;
        try {
            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    file)));
            short[] pval2gray = new short[256];
            int n = 0;
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
                    if (n == pval2gray.length) {
                        if (n == 0x10000) {
                            exit("Number of entries in " + file + " > 2^16");
                        }
                        short[] tmp = pval2gray;
                        pval2gray = new short[n << 1];
                        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, pval2gray, 0, n);
                    }
                    pval2gray[n++] = (short) val;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    // ignore lines where Integer.parseInt fails
                }
            }
            if (n != pval2gray.length) {
                exit("Number of entries in " + file + ": " + n
                        + " != 2^[8..16]");
            }
            return pval2gray;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exit(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.safeClose(r);
        }
    }

private static CommandLine parse(String[] args) {
        Options opts = new Options();
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("frame");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "frame to convert, 1 (= first frame) by default");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("f"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("prfile");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "file path of presentation state to apply");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("p"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("center");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription("Window Center");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("c"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("width");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription("Window Width");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("w"));
        opts.addOption("sigmoid", false,
                "apply sigmoid VOI LUT function with given Window Center/Width");
        opts.addOption("noauto", false,
                "disable auto-windowing for images w/o VOI attributes");
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("file");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "file path of P-Value to gray value map");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("pv2gray"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName(".xxx");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "jpeg file extension used with destination directory argument,"
                + " default: '.jpg'.");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("jpgext"));
        opts.addOption("h", "help", false, "print this message");
        opts.addOption("V", "version", false,
                "print the version information and exit");
        CommandLine cl = null;
        try {
            cl = new GnuParser().parse(opts, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            exit("dcm2jpg: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("unreachable");
        }
        if (cl.hasOption('V')) {
            Package p = Dcm2Jpeg.class.getPackage();
            System.out.println("dcm2jpg v" + p.getImplementationVersion());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (cl.hasOption('h') || cl.getArgList().size() < 2) {
            HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
            formatter.printHelp(USAGE, DESCRIPTION, opts, EXAMPLE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return cl;
    }

private static int parseInt(String s, String errPrompt, int min, int max) {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (i >= min && i <= max)
                return i;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // parameter is not a valid integer; fall through to exit
        }
        exit(errPrompt);
        throw new RuntimeException();
}

private static float parseFloat(String s, String errPrompt) {
        try {
            return Float.parseFloat(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            exit(errPrompt);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
 }

  private static void exit(String msg) {
        System.err.println(msg);
        System.err.println("Try 'dcm2jpg -h' for more information.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

**This is source code for converting jpg to pdf**

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class JPGToPDFConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        selectImage();
    }

    // allow images selection for converting
    public static void selectImage() {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images",
                "jpg", "gif", "png", "bmp");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File[] Files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
            System.out.println("Please wait...");
            for (int i = 0; i < Files.length; i++) {
                convertJPGToPDF(Files[i].toString(), "pdfimage" + i + ".pdf");
            }
            System.out.println("Conversion complete");
        }
    }

    public static void convertJPGToPDF(String strimg, String desc) {
        try {
            // create document object
            Document doc = new Document();
            // create pdf writer object to write the document to the output file
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(desc));
            // get a4 paper size
            Rectangle r = PageSize.A4;
            // read the image
            BufferedImage orImg = ImageIO.read(new File(strimg));
            // initialize image width and height
            int width = orImg.getWidth();
            int height = orImg.getHeight();
            // resize the image that is bigger than A4 size
            if (width > r.getWidth())
                width = (int) r.getWidth();
            if (height > r.getHeight())
                height = (int) r.getHeight();
            // create a blank buffered image
            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            // create graphic2d object from the buffered image
            Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
            // draw the original image on the buffered image
            // so the image is resized to fit the A4 paper size if it is bigger
            // than A4 size
            g2d.drawImage(orImg, 0, 0, width, height, null);
            // store the image data in memory
            ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bas);
            // create image from the image data stored in memory
            Image img = Image.getInstance(bas.toByteArray());
            // centrally align the image on the pdf page
            img.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            // open document
            doc.open();
            // add image to the document
            doc.add(img);
            // close the document
            doc.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

for jpg to pdf convert code you need to download [this jar file iTextPDF](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloaditextpdf510jar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution that turns pages of a dicom file into a pdf using the dcm4che ([the updated re-written one](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che)) and itext libraries.

```
public void convert(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream, String fileName) throws Exception {
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
    ImageReader reader = iter.next();
    reader.setInput(inStream);

    Document document = new Document();
    Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
    document.setPageSize(pageSize);
    document.setMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outStream);
    document.open();

    int pageNum = 0;
    boolean finished = false;
    while (!finished) {
        try {
            // read each dicom page as an image
            BufferedImage bi = reader.read(pageNum);
            if (bi == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't read " + fileName);
            }

            PdfContentByte pdfCB = new PdfContentByte(writer);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(pdfCB, bi, 1);

            // scale the image down to fit on the page width-wise
            if (image.getWidth() > pageSize.getWidth() || image.getHeight() > pageSize.getHeight()) {
                image.scaleToFit(pageSize);
            }

            // align to the middle horizontally
            image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            document.add(image);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
            finished = true;
        }
        pageNum += 1;
    }

    document.close();

}
```